# Maximal ergodic theorem on some dyadic intervals

Tags: pr.probability, ds.dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

What we refer to maximal ergodic theorem in this thread is the following: let $\left(\Omega,\mathcal F,\mu\right)$ be a probability space and let $T\colon\Omega\to \Omega$ be a measurable and measure preserving map. For $f\colon\Omega\to \mathbb R$, define 
$$
M(f):=\sup_{n\geqslant 1}\frac 1n\left\lvert\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}f\circ T^
i\right\rvert.$$
If $f$ is integrable, then for all positive $t$, 
$$\tag{MET}
 \mu\left\{ M(f)\gt t\right\}\leqslant\int_1^{+\infty}\mu \left\{ \left\lvert f\right\rvert\gt tu/2\right\}\mathrm du.
$$
I came across the following maximal functions: for a fixed $\ell\geqslant 1$, 
$$
M_\ell(f):=\sup_{n\geqslant 1}2^{-n}\left\lvert\sum_{i=\left(2\ell-1\right)2^n}^{2\ell 2^n}f\circ T^i\right\rvert.
$$

> Does (MET) holds with $M$ replaced by $M_\ell$?

Since $M_\ell\leqslant 2\ell M$, something can be said but I would like to see whether the dependence in $l$ can be removed.

I tried to look at maximal ergodic theorem along a subsequence, weighted ergodic theorem, etc... But I don't know whether the weights $a_k=1$ if there exists  $n$ such that $\left(2\ell-1\right)2^n\leqslant k\leqslant 2\ell 2^n$ and $0$ otherwise is a so-called "good weight" for the maximal ergodic theorem.

I also tried to follows the proofs of (MET) and to adapt in this case but without success.

Comment: Have you looked at the case when $\Omega=\mathbb Z$, $f$ is the characteristic function of a long interval, $T(z)=z+1$, and $t=\frac 12$, say? It looks like it gives the order of growth $\log\ell$ already. Am I missing anything?

Comment: @fedja I am not sure I follow your example. Which measure $\mu$ do you choose?

Comment: Just the counting one. If you prefer the probability setting, do it on $\mathbb Z/N\mathbb Z$ for large $N$.

Comment: @fedja: Thanks for the example. I will try to work out in details; it looks promising.